# AJAX call to run PHP script within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run a PHP script as soon as Submit button is clicked. I wanted to do an AJAX call as i dint want to refresh the page after the button is clicked. But the below code is not responding upon click.

I have saved the login.php in the same location as my project. Any help or input is appreciated!

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="submit" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "C:\wamp\www\ElitePass\login.php"
        })
        alert("done successully")
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console? Is the request hit to the server?

Comment: The request is not going to  $("button").click(function()  itself. Still unable to figure out how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not targeting your button correctly.

`$("button")` this selector is looking for an element of type "button". Naturally there is none. To target elements by their class names, append dot to selector:

```
$(".button").click(....)
```

Having said that, your code will still not work as you expect it to. Browser security restrictions will prevent loading of files directly from your file system. You need to load stuff via web server. Especially PHP files.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to submit the button but the below query is not responding yet. Do you have any examples of which I can cross check?

          $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:8182/ElitePass/login.php",
                    success:function(){
                        alert("done successully");
                    }
                });

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors that might give you some indication of what could possibly be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can call success like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "C:\wamp\www\ElitePass\login.php",
            success: function() {
                alert("done successully");
            }
        })

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `But the below code is not responding upon click.` Does this mean that even `alert` is not displayed